# Can I install live wallpaper on a Samsung Galaxy 3?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-apollo, live-wallpaper

I am proud owner of Samsung galaxy 3 with android 2.1. Unfortunately it doesn't supports live wallpaper. So is there any alternatives/options for installing live wallpaper with or without rooting ?

Thanks,

Ankur Shah

Comment: Just curious: why should you want to use live wallpapers ? Doesn't that drain your power much quicker ?

Comment: And yes I received my Samsung Galaxy S this week - my first device and I am very impressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it [is possible with root](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_0qI_mMIhw).

Here is the [relevant thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8211216&postcount=103) on how to do it (after you're rooted).

And how to get root [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=778880).